# identifier 'NEW.CITY_POPULATION' must be declared

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I am trying to declare a oracle trigger that will update the city name when the city population reaches 0 but I am getting this error.

````
LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
3/5       PL/SQL: Statement ignored
3/11      PLS-00201: identifier 'NEW.CITY_POPULATION' must be declared
Errors: check compiler log```

here is my code

```CREATE TRIGGER tr_Town_Death AFTER UPDATE 
ON Cities
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    IF NEW.city_population = 0 THEN
        UPDATE Cities 
        SET city_name = 'Ghost town' 
        WHERE city_id = NEW.city_id;
    END IF;
END tr_Town_Death;```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you're going to reference the `:new` pseudo-record in a trigger body, it needs to be prefixed with a colon.
2. A trigger on `cities` generally cannot query the `cities` table.  In this case, it appears that you want to modify the data in the row the trigger is firing for so you'd just want to update the `:new` pseudo-record.
3. Since you want to modify the row that caused the trigger to fire, you'll want it to be a `before update` trigger.

When we make those changes, you'll end up with something like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_Town_Death 
  BEFORE UPDATE 
  ON Cities
  FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF :NEW.city_population = 0 
    THEN
        :new.city_name := 'Ghost town';
    END IF;
END tr_Town_Death;
```